# Sql query with group by clause

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have fetched given below data, now I want the records with Max(Sum1) group by pid but also mention cname of that max value

```
pid   cname   sum1

23     Abc     946

23     Xyz     920

18     Lmn     900

18     Pqr     1500
```

now I want As

```
23     Abc   946

18     Pqr   1500
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do so by using self join with the maxima of sum1 from same table

```
select t1.pid, t1.cname, t1.sum1
from Table1 t1
join (SELECT MAX(sum1) sum1,pid from Table1 group by pid) t2
on(t1.pid=t2.pid and t1.sum1 =t2.sum1)
```

### [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/741db/14)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
select pid, cname, sum1
from Table1
where (pid,sum1) in (select pid,max(sum1) from table1 group by pid)
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a1e6/3)

Comment: @AzizShaikh: Updated..check now